# Using DSolve, For A System With A Piecewise Function, And For Given Boundary & Continuity Conditions

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise, boundary-conditions

I'm trying to solve a system of ODE's, analytically, to find the integration constants.

The system is the following (with zUpper=125 000 and zLower= 200 000).

For 0 <= z <= zUpper:

3 T''[z] == 0.000321062 T'[z]

For zUpper <= z <= zLower:

3 T''[z] == -0.0000114191 + (1.42694x10^-8) T[z] + ((1.42694x10^-8) z - 0.00114155) T'[z]

With boundary conditions of T[0]=100, T[zLower]= 1500, and, with continuity of T[z] and 3 T'[z] at z=zUpper.

These ODE's have general solutions of:

Tupper[z] = 9343.999999999998 c1 e^(0.0001070205479452055*z) + c2 (for 0 <= z <= zUpper)

And,

Tlower[z] = e^((-0.0003805175038051751 + (2.378234398782344 x 10^-9) z) z) (800.25  e^((0.0003805175038051751 - (2.378234398782344 x 10^-9) z) z) + c3 + ( (2.2557139283522667 x 10^10) - (7.407705346716345 x 10^10) c4) Erf[3.9013715732043535 - 0.000048767144665054407 z])

---

I'm able to solve the system numerically, without manually enforcing the two continuity conditions, with the following code (a piecewise function could probably be used instead of an IF statement):

RHS[z_, zUpper_] := If[z < zUpper, 0.000321062 T'[z], -0.0000114191 + (1.42694x10^-8) T[z] + ((1.42694x10^-8) z - 0.00114155) T'[z]]

ODE = 3*T''[z] == RHS[z, 125000]

sol = NDSolve[{ODE, T[0] == 100, T[200000]==1500}, T, {z, 0, 200000}]

Which works, giving the expected curve behaviour (when plotted), and, satisfying the boundary & continuity conditions.

---

*However, when I try to solve the system analytically, to find c1, c2, c3, and c4, I fail to find the correct solution. Details to follow.*

**Attempt #1:**

Using the two boundary conditions and the two continuity conditions below:

expression1 = Tupper[0] == 100 *(boundary condition)*

expression2 = Tlower[zLower] == 1500 *(boundary condition)*

expression3 = Tupper[zUpper] == Tlower[zUpper] *(continuity condition)*

expression4 = 3 dTdzUpper[zUpper] == 3 dTdzLower[zUpper] *(continuity condition)*

where dTdzUpper and dTdzLower are Tupper'[z] and Tlower'[z], and using Solve[] several times, gives:

c1 = 0.4430764116057363

c2 = -1.0264655749034351 x 10^10

c3 = 1.7532815298361826 x10^-8

c4 = 99.99983617337385

These coefficients satisfy one boundary condition (at z = 0), and the two continuity conditions (at z = 125000), but, does not satisfy the second boundary condition (at z = 200000), returning T[zLower]=6400 rather than T[zLower]=1500.

And, for high z's (where this solution diverges from the NDSolve[] numerical solution), the analytically-solved curve becomes less-smooth/jagged (which is easier to see when zoomed in on the plot, though, you can see some of it in the imgur image below).

Here is a comparison of the successful numerical solution, and, the failed analytical solution (from attempt #1):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1gFY.jpg

**Attempt #2:**

When I instead try to solve it with DSolve[], with the two boundary conditions specified, it fails.

(This is probably in part because I don't know how to enforce the continuity conditions in this case).

**Attempt #3:**

When I try to solve it using all four conditions (i.e., two boundary and two continuity) simultaneously, using Solve[] or Reduce[], it returns:

c1 = 1.32705 x 10^-7,

c4 = 0.304509 - (1.34995x 10^-11) c3

which does not give me three of the four coefficients (i.e., c2, c3, and c4).

---

Can anyone please help me solve the system analytically, to find c1, c2, c3, and c4?

Adjacently related, how would I impose the two continuity conditions at z = zUpper for this system, when using DSolve[]?

I have searched many Mathematica help threads, without any luck.

Comment: Just wondering on this **zUpper=125 000 and zLower= 200 000** why is  lower have higher numerical value than upper? Ofcourse it does not make difference to the computer what you call the variables, but for us normal people, I think it is little confusing when reading it. I would myself have made upper=200,000 and lower=125,000.

Comment: It comes from the convention of the physical system it is representing. 

Consider the two regions to be two layers, where zUpper = 125000 to z = 0 is the upper layer, and, zLower = 200000 to zUpper is the lower layer.

Comment: so $z$ represent the vertical height in the physical system?

Comment: That's correct, and T is temperature.